# WorkFlow Formula Question

Tags: workflow, formula

I am trying to use this formula for a WorkFlow but Salesforce keeps giving me errors about two fields which are picklists. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

This is the code and the error is below...

```
(GW_Volunteers__Start_Date__c >=  TODAY() +2)
&&
(ISPICKVAL(GW_Volunteers__Status__c, "Confirmed"))
&&
( ISPICKVAL( GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Shift__r.GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c, "Recurring Shift Job" ))
&&
  (GW_Volunteers__Contact__r.Email <> "")
```

The error message:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected
>   Picklist, received Lookup(Volunteer Job)

Comment: it means the field GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c is a lookup field and you cannot use ISPICKVAL function on this field.

Comment: Ok. As you can see, I am trying to determine if a particular value was selected in picklist. How to do it? I tried it without ISPICKVAL and it told me that it's a pick list that is why I used that function. BTW, it really is a picklist consisting of 4 values. The error I get isn't correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is on the Volunteer Hours object in the Volunteers for Salesforce package?

Looking at the Volunteer Shift object, the Volunteer Job field (GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Shift__r.GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c) is in fact a Master-Detail relationship field, not a picklist. It may be getting rendered in the UI as a picklist, but in the schema, it's a lookup. So I think your formula needs to be:

```
(GW_Volunteers__Start_Date__c >=  TODAY() +2)
&&
ISPICKVAL(GW_Volunteers__Status__c, "Confirmed")
&&
GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Shift__r.GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__r.Name  = "Recurring Shift Job"
&&
GW_Volunteers__Contact__r.Email <> ""
```